# Process Builder can't access Platform Event parameters in formula?

Tags: process-builder, formula-field, platform-event

I created a Platform Event, and now I'm building a process that is triggered by the Platform Event. The Platform Event parameters either contain a ContactId or a LeadId, but not both.

The process I'm building creates a Task Record, and I want to assign either the ContactId or LeadId to the whoIs field. So I'm trying to create it with a formula that checks isBlank on the ContactId, but I can't figure out how to access the Platform Event parameters from the Formula builder.

I can access the fields of the associated object record, but that record doesn't have the contact/lead ids.

Does Formula builder not have access to the Event params?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't add fields to the event to store the Id of the record?

Comment: That's what I ended up doing.

Comment: Note that you _can_ launch a flow, pass the event payload to the flow, and then use the payload in formulas inside the flow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, formulas in Process Builder don't support Platform Event fields (yet).

Sorry  :(

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_process_considerations.htm

Comment: True, but note that you _can_ launch a flow, pass the event payload to the flow, and then use the payload in formulas inside the flow.